# Is the restriction of a periodic function of several variables to a hyperplane also periodic?

Tags: fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

Consider a lattice $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $l \in \Lambda$, $f (x + l) = f(x)$. Let $P$ be a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. What can we say about the periodicity of the restriction $f|_P$?

Comment: Isn't that one of the ways of producing [aperiodic tilings](https://www.nathaniel.ai/de-bruijn-projections/)? So I don't think you can expect the restriction to be periodic in general.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the beautiful illustration! I am aware of the projection method to generate aperiodic tilings but I would like to understand in which conditions the restriction will be periodic?